# how to show a window with sliding effect from right to left in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to show all my windows except Main page from right to left transition style.

I tried this

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <!--<Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
            </Storyboard>-->

            <Storyboard >
                <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="-1200,0,-100,0" AccelerationRatio=".1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

The same if i put stackpanel trigger it's coming from left to right inside the window.

Like wise i need for showing window itself.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `DoubleAnimation` on the `Left` property should do the trick

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard >
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left" From="1920" To="0" AccelerationRatio=".1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: this is working fine as i expected.Thanks a lot.
I am new to wpf can't get it exactly the things.

Comment: please refer some links for these transitions ans animations